# how to fix error Traceback (most recent call last): python?

Tags: python

i have a function in python. this is my function

```
def findstring(dataArray, string):
    for word in dataArray:
        if word.lower() in string.lower():
            found_word_index = string.lower().find(word.lower())
            return string[found_word_index:found_word_index+len(word)].lower()
dataArray = ['lorem', 'ipsum']
string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
print(findstring(dataArray , string))
```

from that code I get result `Lorem , Ipsum`. but if I change variable dataArray to `dataArray = ['string']` i get error

*Traceback (most recent call last):*

I know that error because my variable dataArray not found in variable string. but i don't know how to fix my code. please help me to fix this code

Comment: Please include the rest of the stack trace.

Comment: You should catch the exception inside your function. You don't seem to be handling the case in which the array words are not found in the string.

Comment: yes you right sir, I want to handle where words that are not found result null or 0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help, but I always add exceptions to the code. Here is one bit of code I have currently. It will print out that an error occurred and then continue running the rest of the code. Im sure you probably figured it out in the past two years, but still, maybe itll help someone else.

````
``` try:
    if product_name is None:
        return ""

    url = f"https://www.yoururlorwhatever.com/s?k={product_name.replace(' ', '+')}"
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    price_element = soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "a-price-whole"})
    if price_element:
        return price_element.text.strip()
    return ""
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error getting price for {product_name}: {e}")
    return ""```
````

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34916650)